# "rpmbuild -bb package.spec" produces error: Package already exists: %package debuginfo

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

When i run the command rpmbuild -bb mypackage.spec,  on centos, i get an error

```
error: Package already exists: %package debuginfo
```

following is part of the spec file:

```
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}
BuildRequires: gcc = 4.1.2
BuildRequires: make >= 3.81
BuildRequires: postgresql84-devel = 8.4.9

%description
ElementalCORE 

%prep
%setup -qn pcore

%build
%{__make}

%install
mkdir -p %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}
mkdir -p %{name}
mkdir -p %{_bindir}
install -d %{name}
#This is to ensure that the BuildRoot will be created fresh during the %install section. 
#mkdir -p %{buildroot}
#install -p -m 0755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{name}/obj/ggsnc/ggsnc %{_bindir}

%clean

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%doc NEWS
```

Comment: Is this CentOS 5 or 6? Also, you might want to try throwing %define debug_package %{nil} at the top of the spec file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `%install` in the comment. Replace it with `%_install`.

Comment: What?  Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: 10 years ago: yes, today: no, sorry :D